# MVC razor view with EditorFor helper, check box displayed twice

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Rendered image :

[Image Link](https://lh5.ggpht.com/JufzZ3P1rT6DiNpSA-5GORi5tdI0T7d4rzHBCOd6UKj3QGtqHr8ALIyYrqIMOiuZ90YTauw=s170)

**cshtml**

```
<label>
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => @Model.LeaveDetailsList[i].LeaveType)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.LeaveDetailsList[i].IsSelected)
</label>
```

**View in Browser**

```
<label>
       Annual Leave
       <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." id="LeaveDetailsList_0__IsSelected" name="LeaveDetailsList[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
       <input name="LeaveDetailsList[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </label>
```

Comment: Do you have custom templates? ...

Comment: this can be cause of your CSS class.

Comment: No Im not using custom template

Comment: It doesn't look like the checkbox is being displayed twice, rather there's some sort of CSS image or something being rendered _behind_ the checkbox.

Comment: does it render any differently if you put it in a foreach instead of a forloop?

Comment: Yes Matt I have added inside for loop.Inside foreach also its giving the same result. Can you plz give me the solution.